# bootstrap - adding divs inside columns to align horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and have searched to no avail (including stack overflow) but can't seem to figure this out.  I've got a simple 12 column grid using Bootstrap.  I have a column "".  I need to add a dynamic amount of images to align horizontally and wrap if they don't fit.  I can do this with simple images (img src="">) but each image need to be wrapped inside a div (they are product images so have a lot of formatted information with each one).  When I do this, they align vertically on top of one another.  I've tried "float: left" in the divs and tried with no formatting but the same results.

What am I missing?
The code is simple right now, but I'll add it just the same:
This does what I want (lists images horizontally) but not wrapped in a div.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <img class="categoryImages" src="images/image1.png">
    <img class="categoryImages" src="images/image1.png">
    <img class="categoryImages" src="images/image1.png">
</div>
```

OR this does not work - it lists the images vertically.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div><img class="categoryImages" src="images/image1.png"></div>
    <div><img class="categoryImages" src="images/image1.png"></div>
    <div><img class="categoryImages" src="images/image1.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using bootstraps columns more effectively. E.g. put each image within its own column. `<div class="col-sm-3"><img></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><img></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><img></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><img></div>` to have 4 columns of images.

Comment: The reason I didn't want to do that is that the images are created dynamically so I don't know how many images there will be.  I could create the column code dynamically as well(by counting the images before writing the code) but I wanted the images act separately from the responsive page code, if that makes any sense (I want them to wrap based on space in the column).

Comment: Could you make a codepen to perhaps show what you are trying to do? I think I understand what your getting at.

Comment: Ok, I hope the link works - just created a codepen account!  The first 3 images span horizontally in the column but the last 3 (wrapped in a div) span vertically - I need to get them to span horizontally.  http://codepen.io/shadowfax007/pen/EKaJNM

Comment: Got it. Well you are setting your images within a div. By default, a div is `display: block;`. In your css, use this: `div {display: inline}`. Honestly it would be better if you gave the div a classname so you can specify this item, and leave div alone to be used elsewhere.

Comment: crap!  I didn't catch the default of display:block!  The div is actually going to have a particular class in css, I just didn't add it in the example - I guess I should have to clarify - apologies (I'm not setting all div's to do this).  Thank you so much - this is what I was missing!

Comment: I thought I used to be able to mark a question as answered (by luke) but I can't find it?

Comment: gave the same answer below to get the question answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this in your CSS:

`div {display: inline}`

Or set your div with a particular class name and set that to inline also.